# Copy Down formula from random location

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a super complex macro I am writing, and I need to be able to copy down a formula that gets imported into a sheet in column A and B in a random location.
Is there a way to find the location of where the formula is and copy it down in relation to column C.
This what I have got now but the formula will overwrite some other data. Which is why I need to find the specific cells and copy down from there to the end of column C.

```
Dim LR As Long: LR = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.Goto Reference:="Store_list"
NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Application.Goto Reference:="Store_List"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("CADout").Select

Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("A" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Range("A2:A" & LR) = Range("A" & Lastrow).Formula
Range("B2:B" & LR) = Range("B" & Lastrow).Formula

Application.Goto Reference:="Store_List"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Name = "Store_List"   '
```

[image: Location of the formula however this changes depending on the store]

Comment: I do not understand anything from your question, sorry... Based on what "to find the specific cells"? Do you expect us to tell you that? At least give us an example. You posted a picture without rows and columns headers, without seeing any formula, not telling us anything. Do you want to be pasted on the last empty row, but on a different column? That "random" location cannot be random, to be used in code. **You must explain which logic to be applied to find it**!

Comment: Would "0301" be a 'store' and this must be found like element to determine the row where the first formula to pe pasted? If yes, in which column this "store" exists? In which column the formula must be copied? From where the "store" will be received in order to be used in code?

Comment: Sorry I am struggling to explain this basically what I am doing is importing 4 text files with data and I need to match the store number and floor to the text file. The randomness comes because I don't know how long the text file is.

Comment: The Txt file data would be imported C onwards and I am importing from a folder lookup to the sheet and then I need to copy down the store number and Floor to the end of the data and then import the next file and repeat however when I do this is copies over the previous txt files data.

Comment: I simple do not care what you want importing... I need a simple algorithm in the next terms: I iterate through "A:A" (B:B etc) column of an workbook sheet (imported one, but this is irrelevant) and I need to find **something in the second workbook sheet based on the next logic**:  the search string must be found in column A:A, B:B etc.. When found, in the next column the same row, or 20 columns to the right I must do something... And describe this 'something'. I am asking myself what 'formulas` can you find in a text file, but this is on top of confusion... :)

Comment: The part that is breaking my formula is this as it goes to "A2" is there a way for it to search for active cell and not a2
Range("A2:A" & LR) = Range("A" & Lastrow).Formula
Range("B2:B" & LR) = Range("B" & Lastrow).Formula

Comment: It is possible, but searching for active cell is a bad habit in programming. Who will activate it for the next file to be imported? Can't you find a rule/logic to find it except the fact that temporarily it is selected?

Comment: Not that I can see but I'm very new to this, basically just got dumped it because I knew VBA coding. How would you do look for the active cell and copy down from there?

Comment: You simple use `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address` and you will receive in Immediate Window the selected cell address. (In VBE - CTRL + G)... But active cell is a volatile concept in programming. I would never recommend it.

Comment: What if I name the cell could I use it as a reference and copy down from that named Cell?

Comment: Yes, you can. But would you do that manually? Where is the VBA benefit? If you are able to find it, aren't you able to explain, based on what you physically do in order to accomplish that? –